# R program: list in one column -> data-frame with dimension

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 3840 rows (only one value in columnA). I would like to convert this into a dataframe (40 rows & 96 columns). I tried to use the following code.

```
a1<-a[1:40,]
a2<-cbind(a1,a[41:80,])
a3<-cbind(a2,a[81:120,])
a4<-cbind(a3,a[121:160,])
a5<-cbind(a4,a[161:200,])
a6<-cbind(a5,a[201:240,])
......
a96<-cbind(a95,a[3801:3840,])
```

---

This is too tedious work. Can I use either while loop if loop? If anyone can help me, it will be a great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just redim

```
`dim<-`(a[,1],c(40,96))
```

and you are done (wrap with `as.data.frame` as desired)

Comment: tres snazzy, I like. Maybe replace with `nrow(a) / 40`... even though OP mentions 96 in the title, robustness should be encouraged

Comment: Great answer! Seeing your answer made me realize that `matrix(a1, nrow=40)` would also work.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the `matrix`

```
 matrix(a[,1], nrow=40, ncol=96)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `data.table` like so (noting that this has the advantage that it is easily extended to handle the case when `a` has two or many columns that you'd like to reshape):

```
library(data.table) #1.9.7 + 
setDT(a)[, ct := 1:40]
dcast(a, rowid(ct) ~ ct, value.var = "columnA")
```

(instructions for installing the development version, which has the `rowid` function, [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation))

Test data:

```
set.seed(10932)
a <- data.table(columnA = rnorm(3840))
```

---

If you're feeling parsimonious, here's a one-line version:

```
dcast(a, rowid(ct <<- rep_len(1:40, nrow(a))) ~ ct, value.var = "columnA")
```

And another (this viable in `reshape2` and the current CRAN version of `data.table`):

```
dcast(a, rep(1:ceiling((nrow(a) / 40)), each = 40, length.out = nrow(a)) ~
        rep_len(1:40, nrow(a)), value.var = "columnA")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R method:

```
# Fake data
dat = data.frame(v1 = rnorm(3840))

# Split into columns of 40 rows each
dat.new = as.data.frame(mapply(function(i,j) {dat[i:j,]},
  which(1:nrow(dat) %% 40 == 1), which(1:nrow(dat) %% 40 == 0)))
```

Comment: could skip calculating `1:nrow(dat) %% 40` twice: `which((idx <- 1:nrow(dat) %% 40) == 1), which(idx == 0)`

Comment: Thanks Michael. Although it's just throwing good money after bad. My answer is way more complicated than just going with `matrix(dat$v1, nrow=40)`.

Comment: agreed `matrix` is simplest, but seeing `mapply` in action can be instructive.